# Error executing cross-compiled codes in raspberry pi

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi, qtonpi

I am having problems with a Qt GUI application I created. Basically I created the application in my ubuntu to check if it compiles and works properly, however, if I set up the cross compiler (followed a tutorial and tried a hello world which works properly) and execute my code in the pi the UI does not display properly and basically I cant do anything:
· Text disappears from buttons
· Mouse disappears from screen (therefore cant click buttons)
· Cant navigate buttons using tab key

Any clues? maybe I cant use .ui files in the pi and have to use qml? Thank you in advance.

2 Screenshots of what I get with the pi and what the program should actually look like (ignore the second LCD display):
[what I get http://imageshack.us/a/img17/9986/img20130508093318.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img17/9986/img20130508093318.jpg)
[image: what it should look like]

Comment: Your second image link appears to be broken

Comment: second image link: http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/2038/raspiestubuntu.png

I’ve been told that Qt5 has different rendering platforms, the standard for my compiled version is “eglfs”, which is fullscreen EGL accelerated mobile application style. I need to run it another platform for example xcb or x11 with the command “./myprogram -platform xcb”. Unfortunatelly i only have the following platform options and none of them work: eglfs,linuxfb,minimal,minimalegl,offscreen. I dont now how to install these, i’ll google it see if i can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been told that Qt5 has different rendering platforms, the standard for my compiled version is “eglfs”, which is fullscreen EGL accelerated mobile application style. I need to run it another platform for example xcb or x11 with the command “./myprogram -platform xcb”. Unfortunatelly i only have the following platform options and none of them work: eglfs,linuxfb,minimal,minimalegl,offscreen. I dont now how to install these, i’ll google it see if i can find anything.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=26590&p=321556